# Iterating over unique column values to create dataframes, running functions on the sub dataframes and saving as a single concat

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a master dataframe that has hundreds of key values, it's in the below format:

```
Key,Val1,Val2
a,1,w
a,2,w
a,3,e
b,1,g
b,2,d
```

The idea is to create a loop that creates a new dataframe for every unique key value:

```
Key,Val1,Val2
a,1,w
a,2,w
a,3,e
```

and perform a function over this dataframe and then create a new dataframe that is a concat of all the new dataframes obtained from unique key values. So if the functions were avg and median over val 2, the output would look like:

```
     a     b
avg  1      1
med  2      2
```

The code I've come up with is, the function dataframe is saved in `dffinal`:

```
def regression():
    X=Final.iloc[:,7:-1].copy()
    y=Final[['Sale Rate']].copy()
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=.2, random_state=0)
    sel=f_classif(X_train, y_train)
    p_values=pd.Series(sel[0], index=X_train.columns)
    p_values=p_values.reset_index()
    pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.2f}".format
    return p_values

Final.groupby('Key').agg([regression]).T
```

Please point out where exactly I might be going wrong, I have no idea how to go about this.

error:

```
ValueError: no results
```

Data structure eg : [Function to run ANOVA and give F stat values as the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325304/function-to-run-anova-and-give-f-stat-values-as-the-output/62325577#62325577)

Comment: Why is `avg` for `a` the value `1`? Shouldn't it be `(1+2+3)/3 = 2`?

Comment: Does this do what you want? `df.groupby('Key')['Val1'].agg(['mean', 'median']).T`. Use the actual column where I put `'Val1'`.

Comment: Pls ignore the values, I did not input the exact values as that was an eg

Comment: It might but I need something that would be function agnostic, so could you pls suggest changes within the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, use

```
df.groupby('Key')['Val1'].agg(['mean', 'median']).T
```

and rename index/cols as you wish.

Demo:

```
>>> df
  Key  Val1 Val2
0   a     1    w
1   a     2    w
2   a     3    e
3   b     1    g
4   b     2    d
>>> df.groupby('Key')['Val1'].agg(['mean', 'median']).T
Key       a    b
mean    2.0  1.5
median  2.0  1.5
```

---

Aggregating with custom functions.

```
def custom1(values):
    return values.sum()*100

def custom2(values):
    return values.max() - values.min()
```

Demo:

```
>>> df.groupby('Key')['Val1'].agg([custom1, custom2]).T
Key        a    b
custom1  600  300
custom2    2    1
```

Custom names:

```
>>> df.groupby('Key')['Val1'].agg([('foo', custom1), ('bar', custom2)]).T
Key    a    b
foo  600  300
bar    2    1
```

Comment: ok, this could be used, but in some other use cases this wont work, if I run regression on these values and store the beta coefficients in the new data frame, this approach wouldn't work

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan why not?

Comment: as I cant define  a func to run regression, im sorry I wasn't clear abt this.

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan why can't you define a function to run regression?

Comment: I didn't know you could, is it possible to define a function to run a regression and store the results in a dataframe; so this way the output for the function would be just the F statistic values in a dataframe

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan You can define functions for every operation you wish.

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan no problem, glad that you figured it out!

Comment: I had one more question, is there a way to rename the columns with the Key value, like in your demo

Comment: Could you pls check the edit, cant figure whats going wrong

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan I think it's time to open a new question where you can be more specific since you are now a step further.

Comment: could you help with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327251/applying-a-user-defined-function-to-a-dataframe