# Function to run ANOVA and give F stat values as the output

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

The function im trying to write would take the dataframe provided and calculate the F statistic values and provide those as the output.

Data Format
`Final`

```
Color   Strength   Fabric  Sales
0         1         1         10
1         2         2         15
```

Here Color, strength and Fabric are independent while Sales is dependent.

```
def regression():
    X=Final.copy()
    y=Final[['Sales']].copy()
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=.2, random_state=0)
    sel=f_classif(X_train, y_train)
    p_values=pd.Series(sel[0], index=X_train.columns)
    p_values=p_values.reset_index()
    pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.2f}".format
    return p_values


Final.apply(regression)
```

This is the code I came up with but its throwing an error

```
TypeError: regression() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

What could be going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.apply()`, the dataframe or series is passed as an argument to the function you call. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) explains it more. In order to fix this, instead of:

```
Final.apply(regression)
```

You can simply call `regression()` like this:

```
m_p_values = regression()
```

And now the variable `m_p_values` contains the return value of `regression()`.